# why will i get error react-native-image-picker : NativeModule.ImagePickerManager is null

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I have been on this issue for about 3days now and I have tried everything within my power.

React Native gives me the error

```
react-native-image-picker : NativeModule.ImagePickermanger is Null. To fix this issue, try these steps;

Run react-native link react-native-image-picker in the project root.

Rebuild and re-run the App.
```

When I run react-native link react-native-image-picker, I get ;

```
info iOS module "react-native-image-picker" is already linked
info Android module "react-native-image-picker" is already linked
```

When I rebuild with react-native

```
 react-native run-android
```

And re-run with

```
npm start ( as shown on the screen),
```

It goes back to the original error. It is like a loop.

I am using Andrioid Emulator Nexus 7 on Ubuntu 16.04

secitons of code

```
import { ImagePicker } from 'react-native-image-picker';

 _pickImage = () => {
    const options = {
      noData: true,
      allowsEditing: true,
      mediaTypes: "mixed",
      quality: 0.5,
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      if (response.uri) {
          let fileObj = {
          key: this.state.attachments.length, //first image will have 0 here
          fileInfo: response
        };
        this.state.attachments.push(fileObj);
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          numFiles: parseInt(prevState.numFiles) + 1,
        }))
      }
    });
  };

_pickLiveImage = () => {
    const options = {
      noData: true,
      allowsEditing: true,
      mediaTypes: "mixed",
      quality: 0.5,
    };
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, response => {
      if (response.uri) {
          let fileObj = {
          key: this.state.attachments.length, //first image will have 0 here
          fileInfo: response
        };
        this.state.attachments.push(fileObj);
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          numFiles: parseInt(prevState.numFiles) + 1,
        }))
      }
    });
  };
```

Any help or propositions on this issue will be highly welcomed.

Comment: Where do you use `react-native-image-picker`?

Comment: I use it to in one of my files where I am doing image upload and also giving the option for users to take a picture from screen and upload directly

Comment: Please show me the code that is using it.

Comment: I have updated the question and added my code

Comment: Could you change this? `import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';`

Comment: what sould I change it to ??

Comment: Remove the brackets with my answer.

Comment: Does it work for you? I'm having the same problem using IOS simulator

Comment: removed and it is not still working

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 it is not working

Comment: I'm having the same issue using IOS simulator

Comment: this issue is strange. are you using an IOS system /?

Comment: Can you try react-native-image-picker version ^0.28.1 ? This is with reference to - https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/1137

Comment: Please check https://medium.com/@vinujat85/image-picker-manager-is-null-react-native-f241b9029a23

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works absolutely perfect. When you

## RN >= 0.60

cd ios && pod install

## RN < 0.60

react-native link react-native-image-picker